# Merging Google Spreadsheets: Pulling Specified Data Range Using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, transfer

I want to merge google spreadsheets into another spreadsheet like in this video. I managed to merge it. But I only want to pull data in a certain range. Example: I want to pull data like A1:B20. But in this video it is getting all the data.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-X5CxT2fPbM&list=PLa0SnLUuP_FfEo-SW4RmETLZpthX3ipAw&index=19

I was not able to export a certain range of data from multiple spreadsheets to another spreadsheet with this code.`your text`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.